# how to remove namespace from query string to filter an enum field with OData V4 in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, odata

I want to filter my data with OData V4 based on an enum field. I want to do this without including the entire namespace of the enum in the query string.

I want to run my code by launching this url
https://localhost:7282/weatherforecast?$filter=testEnum%20eq%20%271%27
instead of
https://localhost:7282/weatherforecast?$filter=testEnum%20eq%20TestOData.TestEnum%271%27

I have this code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(opt => 
    opt.Select().Filter().OrderBy());

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    Test1,
    Test2, 
    Test3
}
```

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)],
            TestEnum = TestEnum.Test2
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

To filter the data based on the enum field "testEnum" I need to run the following url:
https://localhost:7282/weatherforecast?$filter=testEnum%20eq%20TestOData.TestEnum%271%27

How do I get this code to work by launching the following url (**without the enum namespace**):
https://localhost:7282/weatherforecast?$filter=testEnum%20eq%20%271%27

When I run this generate this exception:

```
{"Message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. The string '1' is not a valid enumeration type constant.","ExceptionMessage":"The string '1' is not a valid enumeration type constant.","ExceptionType":"Microsoft.OData.ODataException","StackTrace":"   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.MetadataBindingUtils.ConvertToTypeIfNeeded(SingleValueNode source, IEdmTypeReference targetTypeReference)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.BinaryOperatorBinder.PromoteOperandTypes(BinaryOperatorKind binaryOperatorKind, SingleValueNode& left, SingleValueNode& right, TypeFacetsPromotionRules facetsPromotionRules)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.BinaryOperatorBinder.BindBinaryOperator(BinaryOperatorToken binaryOperatorToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.MetadataBinder.Bind(QueryToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.FilterBinder.BindFilter(QueryToken filter)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseFilter()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.get_FilterClause()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Validator.FilterQueryValidator.Validate(FilterQueryOption filterQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings settings)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Validator.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.EnableQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequest request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExecutingContext)"}
```

Comment: maybe cast to int?

Comment: If I launch this url: "https://localhost:7282/weatherforecast?$filter=testEnum%20eq%201"  it generates this eception: ODataException: A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'TestOData.TestEnum' and 'Edm.Int32' for operator kind 'Equal'.